# How to format a moment date and compare with another moment date

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to format a moment date and compare. I know the below is not valid.
How can i do both at the same time?

```
moment('value'). format('MM/DD/YYYY). isSame ( moment ('value). format('MM/DD/YYYT')
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question better.

Comment: I am receiving type error moment(...).format(..).isSame is not a function . I want to format and then compare. Sorry if I am not clear

Comment: moment(...).format(..) returns a string that doesn't have the method isSame. If you want to  do it this way then do moment(moment.format(...)).isSame(....)

Comment: moment(moment('05/20/2022')).format("MM/DD/YYYY")).is Before(moment(Number('1653068264000' )).format("MM/DD/YYYY")) . I am trying to convert timestampin milliseconds . If I use isBefore , its giving me Deprecation warning. value provided is not ISO or RFC format

Answer (score 0):

just compare them?

```
var date = moment('04/22/2022').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
var today = moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY')

if (today > date) {
   // date is from the past
} else {
   // date is from the future
}
```

edit to show using `isSame` method:

```
moment(moment(new Date("may 11 2022")).format("MM/DD/YYYY")).isSame("05/11/2022"); // true
```

Comment: moment(moment('05/20/2022')).format("MM/DD/YYYY")).is Before(moment(Number(1653068264000 )).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))  . I am trying to convert timestampin milliseconds .  If I use isBefore , its giving me Deprecation warning. value provided is not ISO or RFC format

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment().diff to compare.

Check this out: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

```
var a = moment();
var b = moment().add(1, 'seconds');
a.diff(b) // -1000, it is negative, it means a is smaller than b
b.diff(a) // 1000, it is positive which means b is bigger than a.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a note,
when you are using any `momentjs`  queries  than  you should make sure that the datetime is in proper `ISO` fomat , if it is not than you will get the follwing error.

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or
> ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not
> reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date
> formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major
> release.

You should be able to compare them directly.

```
var date = moment("2013-03-24")
var now = moment();

if (now > date) {
   // date is past
} else {
   // date is future
}
```